# How to transform a Luxon DateTme object to a date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, material-ui, luxon

I'm building a DatePicker React with the Material-UI picker library and using Luxon as an adapter.
When I change the calendar date I'm getting an object with DateTime as follow:

[image: Image of the DateTime OBJ]

The code I'm using of the DatePicker:

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={LuxonUtils}>
              <DatePicker
                className={classes.input}
                disableToolbar
                variant="inline"
                label="Date"
                format="cccc, LLLL dd"
                helperText=""
                value={date}
                margin="normal"
                onChange={newDate => {
                  handleDateOnChange({ newDate });
                  setDate(newDate);
                }}
                inputVariant="filled"
                fullWidth
                minDate={new Date()}
              />
            </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

The `on change is giving me back the OBJ I shared in the screenshot and what I would like to get is the date.

I'm doing a `console.log(newDate)` inside the  `handleDateOnChange` and there is no more inside that why I'm not sharing that. The result of console.log() is the one you see above.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can simply use [`toJSDate()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetojsdate)

> Returns a Javascript Date equivalent to this DateTime.

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
const dt = DateTime.local();
console.log(dt);
console.log(dt.toJSDate());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@2.3.0/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I already tried is saying is not a function as an error :(

Comment: @Jakub that's something that should be in the question. Otherwise people like VincenzoC waste their time writing up answers for this you've already tried...

Comment: I found that I was doing something wrong and the solution actually work now :)

Comment: ...and you didn't tell anybody here what you were dong wrong and what the solution was. This is getting better and better

Comment: but if i change the zone like this  DateTime.fromISO(DateTime.now().toISO(), {
      zone: 'America/Edmonton',
    }).toJSDate(); ... this would give me localtimezone date object